# TouchUpInside not responding on iOS5

Tags: xcode, ios5, uibutton, touch-up-inside

I hooked up `touchUpInside` as usual in IB, using new Xcode, build set to iOS 5.0, but my iPhone 4(latest iOS5 right before iOS6 came out) seems not to respond to that. Anybody having same issue?

**EDIT:**

Works on iOS6 simulator, not on real device...

Comment: I am getting same issue , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380304/uibutton-touchupinside-event-is-not-working-in-ios-5-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for gesture recognizers in your code - Apple changed evaluation order of `IBAction` and `Gesture Recognizer`. In iOS6, `IBAction` is always performed first.

Comment: i am getting same issue , how can i resolve this ? this is a link for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380304/uibutton-touchupinside-event-is-not-working-in-ios-5-0